# What does the following error message mean for an inverse matrix?

Tags: python, parsing, matrix, eof

I will include most of my code, because I don't know where the error comes from. Here it is:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
from sympy import Matrix
from numpy import linalg
mu = list(range(16)) # Represent all possible components (of the   metric) in one line array.


t, x, y, z = sy.symbols("t x y z")  # spacetime coordinates.
lettercoords = [t, x, y, z]  # coords in list for easy access
numcoords = [0, 1, 2, 3]  # coords in numbers


class MetricTensor:  # The Metric Tensor Class
def __init__(self, g0, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10, g11, g12, g13, g14, g15):  # Metric components
    self.g0 = g0
    self.g1 = g1
    self.g2 = g2
    self.g3 = g3
    self.g4 = g4
    self.g5 = g5
    self.g6 = g6
    self.g7 = g7
    self.g8 = g8
    self.g9 = g9
    self.g10 = g10
    self.g11 = g11
    self.g12 = g12
    self.g13 = g13
    self.g14 = g14
    self.g15 = g15

def LMetric(self):
    lstmetric = [self.g0, self.g1, self.g2, self.g3, self.g4, self.g5, self.g6, self.g7, self.g8, self.g9, self.g10, self.g11, self.g12, self.g13, self.g14, self.g15]
    lmetric = list(lstmetric)
    return lmetric

def Mmetric(self, lmetric):
    mmetric = Matrix([[lmetric[0], lmetric[1], lmetric[2], lmetric[3]], [lmetric[8], lmetric[9], lmetric[10], lmetric[11]], [lmetric[4], lmetric[5], lmetric[6], lmetric[7]], [lmetric[12], lmetric[13], lmetric[14], lmetric[15]]])
    return mmetric

def InvMmetric(self, mmetric):
        invmmetric = np.linalg.inv(mmetric)
        return invmmetric

def LInvMetric(self, invmmetric):
    linvmetric = list(invmmetric)
    return linvmetric
```

This is where the code for entering the components g0...g15. example:

```
g0 = input("Enter g0:")
...
g15 = input("Enter g15:")


mt = MetricTensor(g0, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10, g11, g12,     g13, g14, g15)
lmetric = mt.LMetric()
mmetric = mt.Mmetric(lmetric)
invmmetric = mt.InvMmetric(mmetric)
linvmetric = mt.LInvMetric(invmmetric)
```

I am trying to create a program that computes the Einstein Tensor from a given metric tensor.I have got the 'math' part covered, but I'm having problems with my code.

When I run the program and enter the 16 g(n) components, this is what I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Irene/PycharmProjects/EFE/EFE.py", line 70, in <module>
    invmmetric = mt.InvMmetric(mmetric)
  File "/Users/Irene/PycharmProjects/EFE/EFE.py", line 42, in InvMmetric
    invmmetric = np.linalg.inv(mmetric)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 526, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc inv
```

It seems that the problem is inversing the matrix symbolically.
If anyone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: python was expecting something like a close bracket, but the end of the file occurred first, make sure your parens and brackets are correct

Comment: Does it say where in particular?

Comment: a good editor like pycharm will

Comment: I am using Pycharm :) The error message comes from Pycharm when I execute the program.

Comment: lol.. are you using input anywhere?

Comment: Yes, added an edit.

Comment: I'm not an expert on those modules, but it seems Sympify is getting passed an empty string

Comment: How so? Is it necessary that I upload my entire code?

Comment: because the error says could not parse '''

Comment: I added an edit, with the error message when I add numbers as components. g0 ... g15